# dynamically loading content for photoswipe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, photoswipe

I am loading the content of photoswipe gallery dynamically. The first 5 image url are loaded from database on the pageload and work like it should be.

### The problem

---

- I click in one of the links, the Photoswipe open loaded with the 5 images that are in the list.
- My code update the list with new 5 images.
- Photoswipe doesn't update the image galery.

My code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#vbar").load(location.href+" #vbar>*","");
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

I have got this advice: [Photoswipe same source code but output not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607175/photoswipe-same-source-code-but-output-not-working). But it is not working.

[**Here is the live page**](http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/newphoto12.php)

Comment: I made an edit into your question, based on the information that you gave. Hope it's what you are looking for.